# What or who or where am I?

Tags: riddle

*I am beneath myself but above my prime*
*Left is on my right and up is nearby,*
*down isn't close... well maybe a bit*

*When our most popular friend joins us,*
*me and (some of) my neighbours like to joke, lol*

*stay close to me and u'll be ok*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the answer is

> The 'K' key on a keyboard

I am beneath myself

> 'K' is below 'I' on the keyboard

but above my prime

> My prime refers to the first letter of My which is 'M'

Left is on my right and up is nearby,

> 'L' is to the right of 'K' and 'U' and 'P' are nearby

down isn't close... well maybe a bit

> 'D' isn't close to 'K' but a bit of down, 'O' and 'N' are.

When our most popular friend joins us,
me and (some of) my neighbours like to joke, lol

> the neighbours are 'J', 'L', ',' and 'O' with 'K' can be used to make 'joke, lol' (there's an additional 'E') As mentioned in the comments, this line may refer to 'JK' as in 'Just Kidding' or a shortened version of 'joke' which could fit better.

stay close to me and u'll be ok

> 'O' is close to me 'K' = OK

Comment: As a form of slang, some people will write "jk" instead of "joke", which fits in nicely with the social behaviour of using the word "lol"

Comment: **THREADKILLER**

Comment: Alternately jk being short for "just kidding".

Comment: Well done, one point though: "our most popular friend" is 'E', because it's the most common letter in the English language.